What are the rules for when to simplify an answer?
My professor has simplified the result of a theorem about Covariance and i don't know why.
The theorem is as follows: Consider simple random sampling without replacement for samples size n in a population size N, Let $Z_i$ be a random variable such that $Z_i = i$ if unit i occurs in a randomly selected sample and 0 otherwise. Then $$\text{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j)=-\frac{n}{N(N-1)}(1-\frac{n}{N})$$.
Proof:
By definition $\text{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j)=\Bbb{E}(Z_i,Z_j)-\Bbb{E}(Z_i)\Bbb{E}(Z_j)$
$$\begin{align}\Bbb{E}(Z_i,Z_j)& = \sum_{z_1=0}^1 \sum_{z_2=0}^1 z_1z_2\Bbb{P}(Z_i=z_1,Z_j=z_2) \\&
= \Bbb{P}(Z_i=1,Z_j=1) \\&
= \Bbb{P}(Z_i=1|Z_j=1)\Bbb{P}(Z_j=1) \\&
= (\frac{n-1}{N-1})(\frac{n}{N}) = \frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)}
\end{align}$$
Then substituing this back into the definiton for equation for Covariance gives:
$\text{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j) = \frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)} - \frac{n}{N}(\frac{n}{N}) = \frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)} - \frac{n^2}{N^2} $
I would have left the result in this form but my professor puts it in the form as stated in the theorem above and I don't know why. Is there rules for what form to leave a result in or is it simply personal preference?

There are no rules. For the record, it's $\operatorname{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j)=\Bbb E(Z_iZ_j)-\Bbb E(Z_i)\Bbb E(Z_j)$, not $\operatorname{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j)=\Bbb E(Z_i,Z_j)-\Bbb E(Z_i)\Bbb E(Z_j)$.

I suspect $Z_i=1$ rather than $Z_i=i$  if unit $i$ occurs in a randomly selected sample

It is personal choice as to what looks tidier; your version involves the subtraction of two values of similar magnitude so your professor might prefer their version which indicates the negative sign of the covariance.
You might have gone for a third representation:
$$-\dfrac{n}{N^2}\left(\dfrac{N-n}{N-1}\right)$$
where the bracketed term turns up elsewhere as the "finite population correction".
